# Execute R-script in C# to render rmarkdown (and provide parameters)

Tags: c#, r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a GUI in Windows Forms (currently trying to do it from the console) that will provide some parameters that are passed to the rendering of an Rmarkdown into any format. In the future I want this to be done from a GUI but to at least get started I figured I would try a basic console application.

I have three files; a .cs-file that should execute the R code, test.R which contains a single line to render the Rmarkdown-file. (If I run this in for example RStudio it works just fine). Finally, I have my rmarkdown-file that basically runs a very basic SQL-query for now.

**ConsoleApp1.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            /* RScriptRunner.RunFromCmd(curDirectory + @"\test.R", "rscript.exe");*/
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin/Rscript.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:/Users/chris/Documents";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:/Users/chris/Documents/test.R";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Report generated");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**test.R**

```
rmarkdown::render("C:/Users/chris/Documents/Rmarkdown.Rmd", params = list(ProdNo = "501", TransTyp = 1))
```

**Rmarkdown.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown-report" 
author: "Chris"
date: "2017"
output: html_document
params:
   ProdNo: '501'
   TransTyp: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r SQLConnection, include=FALSE}

library(RODBC) 

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=myserver\\SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;trusted_connection=true')
```
```{r SQLQuery, include=FALSE}
tempQuery <- sprintf('SELECT * FROM ProdTr WHERE ProdNo =  %s AND TrTp = %s', params$ProdNo, params$TransTyp)
```

```{r Results, include=TRUE}

results <-  sqlQuery(dbhandle, tempQuery)

results
```

```{r Cleanup, include=FALSE}
odbcClose(dbhandle)
```
````

I manage to get the script to at least start execution and provide a secondary console window. However I don't get the expected HTML-file that the R code in itself generates.

If anyone also knows how to make C# open the generated file that would be amazing.

Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.